# Magento connect to verrified reveiews module (avis-verifies ) from different server

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, php, magento-community, development

i want to test "avis verifies" module on a development server.

the problem i facing that the module's already connected to a production server and i can't syncronize the account with the dev server.

thank you for your reply.